# printing a div using jquery print plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, jquery-plugins

i want to print a `tbody` with an id of `alltransactsdaily` in my code using this http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/ plugin to solve the issue of cannot close/dismiss modal when printing.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                  <input type="hidden" name="clinic_idhid" id="clinic_idhid">
                    <div class="table_transactions" id="table_transactions">
                        <table id="mytransactions"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" aria-describedby="dataTables-material">
                            <thead>
                                    <th>Check-up ID</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>                                               
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Check-up Date & Time</th>
                                    <th>Bill Amount</th>
                            <tbody id="alltransactsdaily">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
<button type="button" id="btn_printdiv" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-print"></span> Print</button>
```

now i want to print that `tbody id="alltransactsdaily"` by using this javascript:

```
$("#btn_printdiv").click(function () {
    $("#alltransactsdaily").printElement();
});
```

and when i click the button the console shows:

```
jquery.printElement.min.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined
    at jQuery.fn.init.a.fn.printElement (jquery.printElement.min.js:26)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Patients_report:392)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
```

Comment: Do you have to use a jQuery print library, or are you open to other libraries?

Comment: @KevBot, thanks appreciated reply. yes, i want to use jQuery plugin to lessen my code in printing, and also to solve the issues with cannot dismiss modal

Comment: I mean use another external library. This library works like this `PrintJob.print('#alltransactsdaily')`. It is called [PrintJob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/print-job)

Comment: @KevBot , thanks for reply, i am following this JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9wx9j/. why mine doesn't work?

Comment: anyone answer please. ?

Comment: are you using opera browser

Comment: I think you can use pure javascript for that rather than the plugin. I am not sure about you issue. Because I am not able to view your console.
I can help you without plugin

Comment: @NairAthul but, when i use no plugin, my modal won't dismiss.

Comment: any answers that would make printing code short ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it wont open modal it will open the print on the same page inside a modal popup

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/dqtcb3v8/1/

```
<div id="print-area-1" class="print-area">
    <div style="text-align:right;"><a class="no-print" href="javascript:printDiv('print-area-1');">Print</a></div>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>gh.</p>
</div>

function printDiv(elementId) {
    var a = document.getElementById('printing-css').value;
    var b = document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.title = document.title;
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = '<style>' + a + '</style>' + b;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

Comment: very appreciated answer, but my situation is, inside my modal has the <tbody id="alltransactsdaily">
                            </tbody> and that tbody inside of it, thats what i want to print. can you change your answer sir. thank you

Comment: Okay I am changing the answer to this

Comment: btw, what is this ?<textarea id="printing-css" style="display:none;">html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,df etc.

Comment: It is for formating your printing area. If you dont want any particular element like the button you can class="no-print" can be added so that the printing area will remove it . And also it opens a sample page with html into it inside of that you are pushing to printing element.